# Excel VBA Find a value within a cell from an array and return value to new column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Good day, I am a newbie to VBA.  I have not included the code I have tried, because nothing has even come close.

I have a Data range of about 10,000 that contains the building, department, user name and possibly other information. This information is in column B. The names are not in the same location of each cell and they can be any case and can contain up to 4 words.
[image: Example of list]

I have a Named Range (Full Name) of about 14,000 names in a separate workbook named database.

I need to see if the names show up in the data range list and if so populate column C with the name.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Example code:

```
Sub Full_Name()
    
    Dim iWs As Worksheet, iFn As Variant, lastrow As Long, iDB As Worksheet
    
    iFn = Range("'[Shadow Datafie Database.xlsx]EMCP'!Full_Name").Value
    Set iWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("EMCP")
    lastrow = iWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If InStr(iWs.Cells(i, 2), iFn) > 0 Then
            iWs.Cells(i, 3) = iFn
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried use `InStr`, and maybe `UCase` or `LCase`, and a loop yet?

Comment: Yes I have tried InStr, Vlookup, Xlookup, Index / Match combination, Countifs, Search, @ and {}.

Comment: It might help to [edit] your question with how you tried `InStr`, if you're looking for a VBA solution.

Comment: It would be helpful to put your expected results next to each entry in your table.  As it is now there is too much guesswork to try to establish a rule set for what constitutes a name.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I had to rewrite my code.  .
Option Explicit
Sub Full_Name()
Dim iWs As Worksheet, iFn As Variant, lastrow As Long, iDB As Worksheet
         iFn = Range("'[Shadow Datafie Database.xlsx]EMCP'!Full_Name").Value
         Set iWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("EMCP")
           lastrow = iWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
              For i = 2 To lastrow
                  If InStr(iWs.Cells(i, 2), iFn) > 0 Then
                    iWs.Cells(i, 3) = iFn
                  End If
             Next
End Sub
Crashes at the InStr iFn variable

Comment: Here is an example of what I want returned.
Philadelphia 5 Marketing Bruce Wayne                         Bruce Wayne
Philadelphia 5 Marketing Marketing 
Philadelphia 5 Clark Kent Marketing                         Clark Kent
Philadelphia 5 Marketing Barry Allen x1234                 Barry Allen
Philadelphia 5 Marketing 1-800-sellSell 
Downingtown Rehab 1st Floor John Wayne                 John Wayne
Downingtown Rehab 1st Floor GEMMA ARTERTON Gemma Arterton
Downingtown Rehab 1st Floor Front Desk #2 
Downingtown Rehab 1st Floor Pink Floyd                  Pink Floyd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may work for you:

It assumes your list of names is in an Excel [table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) called `Table1`.

```
Sub FindName()

    'Open the csv file containing your information - building, department, etc.
    Dim wrkBkSrc As Workbook
    Set wrkBkSrc = Workbooks.Open("<path to your file>\Numplan(11).csv")

    'A csv file will only contain a single sheet, so can reference it by sheet position - first and only.
    With wrkBkSrc.Worksheets(1)
        Dim DataRange As Range
        Set DataRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
'    *** OLD CODE ***
'    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'        Dim DataRange As Range
'        Set DataRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
'    End With
    
    'Open the database file and set reference to it.
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open("<path to your file>\Database.xlsx")
    
    'Set reference to the names table.
    'Note: This is an Excel table, not an Excel range.
    '      Press Ctrl+T to turn range into a table.
    Dim NameTable As ListObject
    Set NameTable = wrkBk.Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Table1")
    
    'Only continue if there's data in the table.
    If Not NameTable.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim NameItm As Range
        Dim FoundItm As Range
        For Each NameItm In NameTable.DataBodyRange
            'Find the name within the DataRange.
            Set FoundItm = DataRange.Find( _
                What:=NameItm, _
                After:=DataRange.Cells(1, 1), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False)
            
            'If it's found place the name in the next column along.
            If Not FoundItm Is Nothing Then
                FoundItm.Offset(, 1) = NameItm
            End If
        Next NameItm
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Darren.  I have cut your code into a module.  Changed my Name list to a table.
I cannot get past the first line of code.
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EMCP") I get an out of script range no matter what I do. EMCP is my sheet name.

Comment: And `EMCP` is in the workbook that the code is in?  If the worksheet doesn't exist in the correct workbook it returns a `Subscript out of range` error.

Comment: Yep.  Active workbook is NumPlan(11).csv and active sheet is EMCP.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook` can be different - one is whatever workbook is currently active, the other is the workbook containing the code.  If the `EMCP` sheet is in a file called `NumPlan(11).csv` then it can't be the file containing the code as it's a `csv`` file.  I'll make a few quick changes to the code.

Comment: Thanks Darren.  (Light bulb!)  Yes my code is in my Personal.vlsb workbook.  My bad.  I tried to set the workbook to the NumPlan(11).csv  and the sheet to EMCP but I could not get it to take.

Comment: Have updated the code so it will open the csv file and the Database file while the code sits in your Personal workbook.

Comment: THANKS Darren.  Works wonderfully.  I had to make 1 tweak.
Set NameTable = wrkBk.Worksheets("<worksheet Name>").ListObjects("Table1")
Thanks again.

Comment: Good stuff :) Keep in mind that it will only work on the first occurrence of each name. You'll need [FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) if a name appears more than once.

Comment: Just noticed an error on the `FindNext` link in my previous comment. Their first example uses `Loop While Not c Is Nothing`. It should be `Loop While c.Address<>firstAddress`.